# Application not workig when adding value to <context-param> in web.xml in Spring MVC Web Application Using Maven

Tags: xml, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am creating a web application using Spring Mvc .

I am facing a problem like that when I am not providing value for **context-param** in **web.xml**
then **index page** able to display but when i providing value for **context-param** in **web.xml** then  **index page** is not displaying .

**web.xml  :- when not providing value for context-param**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
          version="2.5">    

    <display-name>Core Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/pages/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

and when I am trying **localhost:8080/CoreWebApp/**  I am getting index.jsp

**web.xml :- when I providing value for context-param**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
          version="2.5">    

    <display-name>Core Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/pages/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
                    /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

and when I am trying **localhost:8080/CoreWebApp/**  I am  not getting index.jsp.

```
Please help me to find out the problem.

My Project Structure is as :-
 CoreWebApp
   |_______________ pom.xml
   |
   |_______________ src
   |                 |_____________ main
   |                                 |___________ java
   |                                 |___________ resources
   |                                 |___________ webapp
   |                                                |____ WEB-INF
   |                                                        |_____ applicationContext.xml
   |                                                        |
   |                                                        |_____ mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
   |                                                        |
   |                                                        |_____ web.xml
   |                                                        |
   |                                                        |_____ pages
   |                                                                |________ index.jsp
   |
   |______________ target
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the log for some exceptions and add them to the question. 
Also Spring MVC searches for xml configuration with name: `"<the name of the dispatcher servlet>+-servlet"` 
Try to rename `applicationContext.xml` to `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` and change the path and accordingly.

Comment: Hey Evgeni, This is not the problem of **mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml** . Due to **Spring Mvc** convention , spring framework look for **<servlet-name>-servlet.xml**.   In my **web.xml** ,At **<servlet-mapping>** , servlet-name is "**mvc-dispatcher**" and i have  **mvc-dispatcher-sevlet.xml** under "**WEB-INF**" folder

Comment: OK. Any exceptions in the log?

Answer (score 0):

Your spring Servlet has a mapping for "/"
And that the path for the index page.