# Specifying context-param in web.xml while integrating Spring and jersey

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven

I am aware that there is already a question asked on this topic but is unanswered [Application not workig when adding value to <context-param> in web.xml in Spring MVC Web Application Using Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919241/application-not-workig-when-adding-value-to-context-param-in-web-xml-in-spring)

I am trying to integrate Spring and jersey , when i add context-param tag to specify the applicationContext.xml the application will not load the homepage(index.jsp under webContent folder)  ,if that tag is reemoved the application loads the homepage but thrn i will not be able to specify the configuration for spring(applicationContext.xml)

**here is my web.xml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>Demo</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>
                             com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages
                    </param-name>
        <param-value>com.im.hellocontroller</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
 <context-param>  
 <param-name>contextClass</param-name>  
 <param-value>
 org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
  </param-value>  
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
 <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
 <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <listener>
 <listener-     class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
<listener-  class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener- class>
</listener> 
</web-app>
```

**here is my pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Inventory-Management</groupId>
<artifactId>Inventory-Management</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>

<dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jersey -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jersey + Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!--  Hibernate dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.36</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>



<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**here is my applicationContext.xml:**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.im.hellocontroller"/>


<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/imanagement" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean> 

 <bean id="sessionFactory"  
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />  
<property name="annotatedClasses">    
        <list>    
            <value>com.im.beans.User</value>    
        </list>    
    </property>   
<property name="hibernateProperties">  
<props>  
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop> 
<prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop> 
<prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>  
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>

 </props>  
</property>  
 </bean> 

</beans>
```

applicationContext.xml is in the classpath (ie src folder),web.xml in under WEB-INF,index.jsp is under WebContent

Thanks for any help !

Comment: The SpringServlet from Jersey does not even compare to the DispatcherServlet from WebMVC. Its config is quite limited compared. I forked and changed it. You might end up the same.

Comment: But i want to make sure that applicationContext.xml file is read , what to do ?

Comment: Your problem might be that Jersey does not create a sub-context just as DispatcherServlet does. This is my I have forked it.

Comment: Did you get any stacktrace in logs

Comment: Why are you using `RequestContextListener`

Comment: Aslo `contextClass` is using with spring-MVC dipatcher servlet ,not with jersy. Please correct configuration.see http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-spring-integration-example/

Comment: @Tom , in stack trace if context-param was not included i am getting **java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?** , if context-param is added then application doesnt load,Thanks for your help guys really appreciate it !

Comment: Did you guys find any fix to this ?i am stuck for over 3days !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic problem is you mixed up xml and annotationConfigs.
You need to know the relation between **contextClass** and **contextConfigLocation** context params and how [ContextLoaderListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoader.html) will make use of it.

1. contextClass : refers the configuration class. You mentioned here it as  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.html)
2. contextConfigLocation : this is the location where it spring's bootstraper will search for config. You specified contextClass as AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext, for that you should give the package name where your Spring bean configuration class resides.I assume you have such class annotated with `@Configuration`

If you have no such @Configuration annotated class remove contextClass and put only contextConfigLocation  param with your xml path as value. By default `ContextLoaderListener`take the xml based.
Here is an example of [migrate to java config from xml based spring](http://www.robinhowlett.com/blog/2013/02/13/spring-app-migration-from-xml-to-java-based-config/)

You can find a ready to adapt example of jersey integration [here](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-spring-integration-example/).

Next thing I still confused, why you are using `RequestContextListener` for REST application. If you don't have any special purpose as per [its documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextListener.html) remove it. If you want to use it this [example](http://javaswamy.blogspot.in/2010/01/making-jersey-work-with-spring.html) will help

Also find some useful detail regarding the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075790/how-to-register-spring-configuration-annotated-class-instead-of-applicationcont)

Comment: Thanks for your help Tom !

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution for my question , i was mixing the jersey1.x and jersey2.x maven dependencies (that of sun and glassfish